# Overload-resolution in generic constructors

Tags: c#, generics, overloading, overload-resolution, constructor-overloading

I created a mockup class to ilustrate the question:

```
 public class Anything<T>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Generic typed constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="param1"></param>
        public Anything(T param1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm generic typed constructor");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// String typed constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="param1"></param>
        public Anything(string param1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm string typed constructor");
        }
    }
```

Whats up if I build Anything of string object? There is no way to differentiate both constructors. It's a bad practice define another constructor with the same number of parameters?

[image: Two constructos looks equal]

Comment: Actually there is way. Compiler will use non generic overload if possible. So its not a bad practice if there is something especial about string

Comment: What exactly is your question? How this works (read about overload resolution, see duplicate), which one will be called (run it) or whether this is a bad practice (opinion-based)? If you provide a real use case, alternatives can be shown. The use case will explain why you think you need a string overload in the first place, and from that will follow how to mitigate the ambiguity. Again, see duplicate. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler will always choose the most specific overloaded method, that is the one with the `string`parameter in its signature. Even if you have a generic method (or constructor in your case) the explicitly typed `string` parameter is the most specific one. Thus

```
new Anything<string>("test");
```

will output

> I'm string typed constructor

---

From a software engineering perspective, it is indeed a bad practice because it would not be clear to the user of the class why for example the constructor with the `string` parameter would exhibit different behavoir than the generic one.